# Obtener el texto del Siguiente div

Tags: jquery, div

Quiero obtener el texto de el siguiente DIV a partir de un boton cliqueado, espero me puedan ayudar

Mi código es el siguiente

```
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
    <img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="images/user.png" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
    <span class="media-heading"> Nombre - </span><i> Fecha </i><span class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="2" onclick="obtener($(this),event)" title="Obtener"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
    </span><div class="texto m-t-10">Texto a obtener</div></div></div>
```

Estoy Utilizando la siguiente función:

```
function obtener(edit,e){
e.preventDefault();
id = $(edit).attr("id");
alert($(this).next("div").html())};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El método `next()` sirve para buscar "hermanos" es decir, elementos que están dentro del mismo contenedor, en tu caso `button` está dentro de `span` pero tu `div` está fuera del `span` por lo tanto no lo puedes encontrar con `next()`

Te dejo dos opciones para conseguir lo que quieres hacer

### Opción 1

Mueve el `div` dentro del `span` y en tu función de js ya estas utilizando `edit` como argumento y estas pasando `$(this)` como valor para `edit` así que puedes modificar tu función. El ejemplo completo se encuentra a continuación:

```js
function obtener(edit,e){
    e.preventDefault();
  alert(edit.next("div").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
    <img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="images/user.png" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
    <span class="media-heading"> Nombre - </span><i> Fecha </i><span class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="2" onclick="obtener($(this),event)" title="Obtener"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
    <div class="texto m-t-10">Texto a obtener</div>
    </span></div></div>
```

### Opción 2

Puedes asignar un `id` a tu `div`. El ejemplo completo se encuentra a continuación:

```js
function obtener(edit,e){
    e.preventDefault();
  alert($("#divDeseado").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
    <img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="images/user.png" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
    <span class="media-heading"> Nombre - </span><i> Fecha </i><span class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="2" onclick="obtener($(this),event)" title="Obtener"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
    </span><div id="divDeseado" class="texto m-t-10">Texto a obtener</div></div></div>
```

En ambos casos puedes utilizar `.html()` o `.text()` para obtener el texto que está dentro del `div`

Comment: Genial, no lo había visto así... gracias por la ayuda eres una master @HeytalePazguato